# Code generation based on dropwdown input

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

Hello you selflessly helpful lot,

I am trying to create some code. I need 3 dropdown menus. The first dropdown menu provides the name of a product, and determines the options available of the the second dropdown menu, and the choice made in the second dropdown menu determines the options available from the third and last dropdown menu.

If for example the following choices are made:

dropdown 1: Product 2;
dropdown 2: option 3;
dropdown 3: option 5.

then a code should be generated based on the choices, ie. "02.03.05".

The code should be shown in a text field, along with a report. I plan on personalising each code into whether they require further action or not, and what the justification is. 
Eventually, I hope to end up with something like this:

"Problem code: 02.03.05.
Description: Product 2 encountered a problem at location 3 invloving part 5.
Action: No further action required.
Justification: (whatever)"

So a predetermined answer for the action and justification fields are presented depending on the code generated.

Any ideas?

Comment: First you should organise your data, your first dropdown loads from a JSON data set (or the first can be hard-coded), then based on that choice you make an ajax request for the next correct data set and populate the next box with it etc

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this depends on the amount and relativity of the options you want to add, or how many scenarios you have.
if for example dropdown1 decides for sizes for dropdown2. 
One solution, if your scenarios are simple would be to have function with a case to create your `<option>..</option>`. ie.

```
<select id="setSize">
     <option value='1'>1</option>
     <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>
```

call this switch statement on dropdown1 change and so on

```
switch($(this).val()) {
    case 1:
        $(this).append('<option value=1>Small</option>');
        $(this).append('<option value=1>Medium</option>');
        break;
    case 2:
        $(this).append('<option value=1>Large</option>');
        $(this).append('<option value=1>XL</option>');
        break;
    default:
        $(this).append('<option value=1>Etc</option>');
}
```

hope its clear enough!

**edit:** for a more complicated scenario, the problem appearing here is the amount of option each dropdown created for the next dropdown. if its 2-3 AND standard, then this quickfix should do the trick, otherwise you should do an ajax request to get the information for the `<option>..</option>`